Lost in the sky

Solve on Penpa+
Across
1. It's very surprising for men LaBrie harassed to pick the wrong side in biopic (7)
5. Word written twice on the Saudi flag (and the opening of Annie Hall, in retrospect) (5)
9. Jafe, with cover from Moore, stealing silver icon (5)
10. Short moneylender losing some hair (3)
11. West Banker, according to El País, seen with hardcore singers? (5)
12. SoCal city, only 50% desert (4)
14. Yank lines up the wrong way (4)
15. A constrictor, or Python's "Constructor", as a pun (that may be "punt" without the final T) (3)
18. Running any road, to Take the Time that's coming (7,3)
20. "Tap" is an anagram of "apt" (3)
21. Husband's given one half of a pair marketed for couples? (3)
22. At a military disadvantage: Certain to be truncated like 3 vis-à-vis 3.14159... (10)
23. Church refused to attract member (3)
25. I don't know how to put this, and I forgot to bring this up earlier... In short, these people are authorities in the field! (4)
26. Cut – clipboard command of yesteryear? (4)
30. Muslim festival attended by lethargic, exhausted Iberian fighter (2,3)
31. 17 down menace erasing "icon" from dictionary (3)
32. Entertained by Northern European, you enjoy greatly (3,2)
34. Planets without the first sign of life lead to heated argument (5)
35. One undercover, or one under cover? (7)
Down
1. Old lady checks the papers of hired help (5)
2. German banned from Baltic city located on an eponymous gulf (that is, a narrow body of water) (3)
3. Heartlessly encrypted, like some places for those Learning to Live (2-2)
4. Another novel series penned (4)
5. Where the Proclaimers expected to fall down is our yard? Too unexpected! (2,4,4)
6. I found that hilarious about California native (5)
7. Network that showed Game of Thrones with male bimbos at the forefront – it has a huge impact (1-4)
8. Did picture drive team insane? (6)
13. Playing cards, and playing tennis, topless (5)
16. Setter is overwhelmed by the single word spoken by a recurring Python character describing inflammation, in medical compounds (-4)
17. Big city container Portnoy and Emily sent back after triplets go missing in the end (10)
19. Hungers for bread in Iwo Jima, with a pinch of salt (4)
20. On vacation, Petrucci comes into contact with small piece of Greek writing forming a work of art housed in the Vatican (5)
21. The man had right for a long winning streak (6)
24. Parrot's mouth grabbing a cocoa kernel (5)
25. Not sufficiently sedated (5)
27. One recording per concert! Quota ultimately displayed at the front (5)
28. Sun Myung Moon went to prison for misfiling them, losing time, leading to dismissals (4)
29. Dirty, miserable Democrat! (4)
33. Power, energy, a little perkiness (3)

Filled grid:

 

Clue explanations:

 


I think 11 is {evb ("onaxre", v.r. evire, va fcnavfu) + up (uneqpber), nyy tbvat jrfg}

@juicifer Added, thank you!

There's a nic(h!)e hidden theme to this crossword too... rot13(gur nyohz VZNTR/FNAQ/JBEQF ol QERNZG/URNGRE - jvgu ersreraprf gb genpxf NABGURE QNL, FHEEBHAQRQ, naq ZRGEBCBYVF—Cneg V: "Gur ZVENPYR naq gur FYRRCRE". Cyhf gur gvgyr 'Ybfg va gur fxl' vf gur bcravat yvar gb gur nyohz-bcravat genpx 'Chyy Zr Haqre'.)
